# Find stationary points of QCQP

Tags: matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

I'm given the following:

$$\begin{align}
\min &\qquad x^TQx\\
\mathrm{s.t}&\qquad  x^TAx <= 1
\end{align}$$

where $A$ is a positive definite.

I'm not sure if and or how this would change the original optimization with the original constraint of $g(x) = x^Tx = 1$ since here we could use the Identity matrix $I$ for A since $I$ is PD?  Would the answer be the same and the constraint be binding at optimality?  At optimality for the equality constraint the answer is the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda$ of Q and its associated normal eigenvector stationary point.

Comment: The minimum is clearly the minimal eigenvalue of $Q$, attained at the corresponding normalized eigenvector $x$. You may test your statements against the answer and see if they make sense. The problem is, of course, non-convex.

Comment: Yes you are both correct it's a non-convex optimization problem and yes the smallest point is the smallest corresponding orthonormal eigenvector to the smallest eigenvalue.  One question, how would this change if the constraint was $x^TAx <= 1$ where A is positive definite?

Comment: When $Q$ is itself positive definite, the minimum is attained at $x=0$. Unless the asker meant $x^\top Ax\ge1$.